# error writefile failed = 0x3 (3)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to Create my Own Test Certificate

I run the below line  visual studio 2010 command prompt in admin mode.

```
makecert -sv Test.pvk -n ""CN=Test file" Test.cer -b 01/01/2011 -e 01/01/2015 -r
    Error: WrtieFile failed => 0x5<5>
```

it is getting error and says

```
error writefile failed = 0x3 (3)
```

[image]
what is the wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you tried specifying an output file in a directory other than `System32`?

Comment: I have tried. but same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have typo in your commands please check near ""CN=Test file" should be like "CN=Test file"

like below

```
makecert -sv Test.pvk -n "CN=Test file" Test.cer -b 01/01/2011 -e 01/01/2015 -r
    Error: WrtieFile failed => 0x5<5>
```